# select2 required oninvalid custom text not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

Here i have `select` `option` using `select2`, it works fine, but here i want `select2` `required` with `oninvalid` `custom text` and when i select and save with button form, but it keeps displaying invalid text on button and can't save

This works if we directly select select2 and fill in the input and directly save

But it doesn't work when I press the `button` in the beginning and `select` the last one `select2`, it will keep displaying the text and that's the problem is there any way to fix it

```js
$(".select").select2({
 placeholder: "Pilih . . .",
 allowClear: false,
 });
```

```css
.w-100{
  width: 50%;
}
.btn{
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<h4>FORM 1</h4>
<form action="ins.php" method="POST" >
  <select  class="select w-100" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Tidak Boleh Kosong')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"  required="" >
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="1">Opsi 1</option>
      <option value="2">Opsi 2</option>
      <option value="3">Opsi 3</option>
      <option value="4">Opsi 4</option>
      <option value="5">Opsi 5</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input  type="text" class="w-100"  oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Tidak Boleh Kosong')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"  value="" required="" />
  <br><br>
  <button class="btn btn-success">Simpan</button>
 </form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `oninput` event is only valid for input / textarea elements. For select elements `onchange` should be used instead. The `onchange` event occurs when the element looses focus and has a changed value.

Updating the select to use onchange as follows will correctly trigger the event.

```html
  <select  class="select w-100" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Tidak Boleh Kosong')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"  required="" >
```